# Unable to boot GRUB while trying to set up dual boot configuration

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 21.10. I can boot into either from my UEFI settings, but when I boot into Ubuntu I get no GRUB window.

No matter what I try to do, I just can't get GRUB to detect windows. I've tried os-prober, I've tried enabling os-prober, but it can't find my Windows installation. I have them installed on two different SSDs.

I'm a bit new to Linux and Ubuntu.

If I run `sudo parted -l` I get this:

```
Model: ATA CT250MX500SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   250GB  250GB  ext4


Model: Samsung SSD 980 1TB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata
```

Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary:

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.10 on sda2
OS#2:   Windows 7 on nvme0n1p1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic root=UUID=c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sda2      ext4  228G   13G  204G   6% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: P2.00(5.14) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
No EFI in dmseg.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,d7e3d59a-ae4b-4c5e-b1ae-df8871f8f774,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........q.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.8.0. .1.T.B....................A...........................%8.!........4..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.6.4.A.N.L.0.T.7.1.8.0.8.1.R........BO..NO........u.C.T.2.5.0.M.X.5.0.0.S.S.D.1....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.2.6.2.6.E.2.4.1.F.3.7. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,305ddbb2-90eb-465a-9f1d-f7af7ca1c812,0x800,0x74706000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO

56ead1707eebecdf4be3d0ac81874426   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
56ead1707eebecdf4be3d0ac81874426   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
37130342d94333ead74a46c7288ce233   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p1   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 2A9A5038-3C0B-4D1C-A554-33ADC55F7AAE
          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1  2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data
Disk sda: 232.89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 50981654-A385-420C-9110-0E90ECA36891
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
sda2  1050624 488396799 487346176 232.4G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:250GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA CT250MX500SSD1:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:250GB:250GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 980 1TB:;
1:1049kB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs::msftdata;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                  
├─sda1      vfat     C383-C3F6                            d7e3d59a-ae4b-4c5e-b1ae-df8871f8f774       EFI System Partition
└─sda2      ext4     c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3 02d643a4-3f11-4ae4-a102-05bd7ade431a       
nvme0n1                                                                                              
└─nvme0n1p1 ntfs     FAE00213E001D6B3                     305ddbb2-90eb-465a-9f1d-f7af7ca1c812       Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                 617.7G  34% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/sda2                      203.4G   6% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-29-generic   c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-21-generic   c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=c90fc845-57ac-4db7-b4e4-d5b1771ffba3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C383-C3F6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  46.453781128 = 49.879367680   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  40.824775696 = 43.835269120   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  16.668518066 = 17.897684992   boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-21-generic                 1
  40.824775696 = 43.835269120   boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic                 1
  16.668518066 = 17.897684992   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  46.439990997 = 49.864560640   boot/initrd.img                                1
  96.682163239 = 103.811682304  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-21-generic              2
  46.439990997 = 49.864560640   boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-29-generic              1
  96.682163239 = 103.811682304  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Sep 19 09:00 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43263 Sep 19 09:00 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Sep 19 09:00 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Sep 19 09:00 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Sep 19 09:00 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Aug 30 13:33 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Sep 19 09:00 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Sep 19 09:00 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.10 entry (sda1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode? ` [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo Legacy` Or for more details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I did try running the boot repair tool before I saw this reply, so I apologize, but I still have the issue. I'll get the BootInfo summary report. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wXYCZ9Y2wP/

Comment: So what happens if you don't use UEFI boot, ie do nothing when computer starts? Also run command **sudo parted -l** and post output into your question.

Comment: @PaulBenson If I don't UEFI boot, it just goes straight into Ubuntu or Windows depending on how I've got my boot order set up. I also added the output for sudo parted -l to my question.

Comment: Your nvme drive does not have an EFI partition/ESP. I think that is the reason why Grub cannot find your Windows installation. Looking in my grub.cfg the Windows entry refers to the EFI with a number. I don't know how to adapt this to your situation though. However you can install Grub2Win in Windows and see if it detects both OS's. If it does make that your main/default bootloader. Some people don't like this program, but I never had any problems with it.

Comment: Have never seen a UEFI boot entry refer to a GUID/partUUID of a NTFS partition which your Windows entry has. UEFI wants to boot from an ESP - efi system partition for both Windows & Ubuntu which is FAT32. Does Windows entry in UEFI actually boot? If so custom UEFI that is different than the standard.

Comment: @JoepieEs I have a theory as to why my boots all messed up! So, my pc came with an hdd, and I installed an ssd which I wanted a fresh start on, so I did a fresh install of windows on it. I guess I messed up somewhere, cause I could not boot onto the ssd without the hdd present. I tried what I saw [link] (https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15729-main-sdd-wont-boot-without-secondary-hdd-2.html) and it seemed to fix things? Anyways, I'll try Grub2Win. If that doesn't work, should I try just doing a fresh install of windows?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it! Grub2win didn't work at first. I tried part 2 of this guide here: https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/boot-configuration-data-missing.html - Basically, I put a windows 11 install on a usb stick using their media tool and I booted it. Opened up recovery mode, went to troubleshoot>command prompt and ran:

```
bootrec.exe /Rebuildbcd
bootrec.exe /Fixmbr
bootrec.exe /Fixboot
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
```

And then, grub2win seemed to install just fine, and I could set up a bootmenu.

Comment: Glad you got it working! +1